# How do you implement a HTML form which accepts text input meant for tag/hashtag values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express

**Update 1**

I managed to locate a solution called [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify) but I have problems implementing it. 
As a start, I am trying to implement only the simplest version of Tagify.

Below is the content of my `show.ejs` file.

As you might expect, I also have a routes folder containing the *CRUD* routes and logic but I do not think that should be touched for this purpose?

I also ran the command to install the *Tagify* module in my `node_modules` folder but I am not exactly clear where I should import the contents of that folder, and whether I should be doing this

```
import tagify from ....
```

or

```
var Tagify = require("...")
```

Though I believe it is the latter.

```
<% include ../partials/header %>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h1 style="text-align: center">Create a New Entry</h1>
                <div style="width: 30%; margin: 25px auto;">
                    <form action="/events" , method="POST">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="price" placeholder="Price" min="0.01" step="0.01">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="image" placeholder="image url">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="description" placeholder="Describe the place">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <textarea name='tags2' placeholder='Movie names'>The Matrix, Pulp Fiction, Mad Max</textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit!</button>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                    <a href="/events">View all events</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var input = document.querySelector('textarea[name=tags2]'),
                tagify = new Tagify(input, {
                    enforceWhitelist: true,
                    whitelist: ["The Shawshank Redemption", "The Godfather", "The Godfather: Part II", "The Dark Knight", "12 Angry Men", "Schindler's List", "Pulp Fiction", "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", "Fight Club", "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring", "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back", "Forrest Gump", "Inception", "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers", "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", "Goodfellas"],
                    callbacks: {
                        add: console.log,  // callback when adding a tag
                        remove: console.log   // callback when removing a tag
                    }
                });
        </script>

    <% include ../partials/footer %>
```

---

**Original question**

For example, if I create a restaurant reviews website and am creating the page with a form so I can add new restaurants to the site, I would like to include fields like:

1. Restaurant name
2. Address
3. Average price per pax

Further to this, let's say I want to add a field where every semi-colon separated string can become something like a tag. Examples: "italian" "western" "family-friendly". How are possible ways I can implement this? It seems the standard HTML forms do not allow this and I need to import something - Am I wrong?

Currently learning & experimenting on a MEN stack (MEAN less Angular)
Much thanks in advance.

Comment: It's what we call a collection, you can handle it is using multiple input form, or you a 'chips | tags | token' library like https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/ for exemple

Comment: Did you manage to get Tagify to work? The code seems OK from your `ejs` example